# why does zip truncate the data in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm experiencing some strange behavior using zip; I'm basically trying to have an RDD of key-value pairs where value is just an index, e.g. I initialize an rdd 'f':

```
f = sc.parallelize(tokenizer('a fox jumped over the rabbit')).flatMap(lambda x: ngrams(x)) 
f.count()
52
```

and then do:

```
ind = sc.parallelize(range(f.count()))
ind.count()
52
```

but

```
f_ind = f.zip(ind)
f_ind.count()
48
```

I don't understand why some elements are being lost?

Comment: And now please without "..." and "etc": http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Are you sure that `sc.parallelize` is returning the right number of results?

Comment: ok I updated the question to appease @Kay -- and yes, it does seem like `sc.parallelize` is doing the right thing

Comment: I recommend just using zip with index in spark, I find it had to believe that something this simple would be buggy, so there is likely a part of the code affecting this you aren't showing us

Comment: I agree that's why I'm trying to find out what's causing this :) you're right there is other code for the tokenizer and the ngram parser but everything after the first line above it's complete. But what do you mean by "just use zip with index"? Am I missing some part of the api?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a `SparkRDD` `zip` operation requires that two RDDs have same number of elements *and* the same number of elements *per partition*. This last requirement is what is violated in my case above. There doesn't seem to be a fix for this (but see e.g. http://www.adamcrume.com/blog/archive/2014/02/19/fixing-sparks-rdd-zip).